# the path is not of a legal form error c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to set Menu_Track path through AudioHandler() on Form1_Load but it is not adding the path to Menu_Track. mts mts mts mts

```
namespace NGTurnBased
{
class MyVariables
{

    public static string Menu_Track;
    public static SoundPlayer AudioPlayer = new SoundPlayer(Menu_Track);
    public static int Essence = 0;


}
}
```

---

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        rdb_Ryu.Click += Character_Selected;
        rdb_momiji.Click += Character_Selected;
        getForm();
        AudioHandler();


    }
   private void AudioHandler()
    {
        if (currentForm != "test")
        {
            MyVariables.Menu_Track = @"C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\NGRPG\Volf_BGM.wav";
        }
        MyVariables.AudioPlayer.Play();

    }
```

Comment: Your Menu_Track variable looks empty when the SoundPlayer tries to use it.

Comment: You must initialize Menu_Track before you initialize MenuSelection with it. BTW, you should really choose better names for your variables... When I see a variable named MenuSelection, it's not intuitive at all that it's a SoundPlayer

Comment: Fiend Busa please don't edit my answer, if you have new information about the question. Add it in your initial question.

Comment: Very sorry, this is my first time posting on this website. I thought I was replying to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string Menu_Track;
public static SoundPlayer MenuSelection = new SoundPlayer(Menu_Track);
```

Here you should specified path to the SoundPlayer. At the momemnt you have new SoundPlayer(null) -> which is not valid path for a wav file.

Edit:
Thanks for comment @ThomasLevesque

Comment: Menu_Track is null, not an empty string

Comment: I have Menu_Track set to a path during form_load

Comment: Very sorry, this is my first time posting on this website. I thought I was replying to your post

Comment: @FiendBusa No problem just edit your question and someone will try to help you.

Comment: Thanks.I was able to fix the path is not of a legal form problem but I can't seem to change the value of Menu_Track with AudioHandler()